# Unable to align ListItem text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, listitem

I have this material-ui list:

```
<List dense>
  {this.state.issues.map((item, i) => {
    return <Link target="_blank" to={item.issue_url} key={i}>
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemText primary={item.issue_state}/>
        <ListItemSecondaryAction>
          <IconButton>
            <ArrowForward/>
          </IconButton>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </ListItem>
    </Link>
  })
  }
</List>
```

`issue_state` is obtained from MongoDB. Can I add another column to my list showing another field from the database? I tried:

```
<ListItemText primary={item.issue_state}/>
<ListItemText primary={item.issue_title}/>
```

This displays what I want but the issue_title test is centered. I'd like it left aligned. Can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried alignItems property ?

Comment: Yes. I tried `alignItems='flex-start` but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListItemText` component renders with the following CSS style that allows it to be flexible to grow and shrink according as the width and height of its content.

```
flex: 1 1 auto;
```

Its ancestor `ListItem` component renders as an `inline-flex`. 
AFAICT, the results you're looking to achieve can't be done without overriding these styles. Not to worry, there are other ways to go that uses available APIs exposed in the component.

Never mind that the name for the component seems to be misleading that its usage is specific for rendering text in the list item.
A closer look in the [`ListItemText` component API documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-text/) shows that the `primary` property is of the `node` type.

That implies that the `ListItemText` can be used to render string, function, and `React.Element` in a manner similar to the snippet below.

```
<ListItemText primary={<div>Foo<br/>Bar<br/>Baz</div>} />
```

[image: Foo Bar Baz]

There is also the `secondary` property that renders the elements with textual emphasis.

```
<ListItemText primary="Foo" secondary={<div>Bar<br/>Baz</div>} />
```

[image: Foo Bar Baz]

If you need more control over the children of the `ListItemText`, the API allows for the flexibility to write it this way

```
      <ListItemText>
        <Typography variant="subheading">Foo</Typography>
        <Typography variant="body1" color="textSecondary">Bar</Typography>
        <Typography variant="body1" color="textSecondary">Baz</Typography>
      </ListItemText>
```

[image: Foo Bar Baz]

Comment: Thans. I tried this `<ListItemText primary={item.issue_state<br/>item.issue_number}/>` but it gives me this error:

`ERROR in ./client/issue/Issues.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (64:65)`

Comment: You have set primary to an array. It must be a `node` (i.e. a `React.Element` with its children)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "You have set primary to an array"?

Comment: No worries. I was vague in my reply to your comment. Let me try again. For the primary prop, `{item.issue_state<br/>item.issue_number}` assigned. This value is  actually an array of __3 React elements__ (_i.e_ `item.issue_state`, `<br/>`, `item.issue_number`). React supports have a tree of elements as children or renderProp value. If you wouldn't want to render the elements in a wrapping `div`, you can wrap all 3 React elements instead in a `React.Fragment`.

Comment: Ah perfect. Thanks for the help.